# Best Android Emulator that supports Android L for development

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

Are there any Emulator's that support Android L of August 2014 that I could use for Development when compiling my application?

Comment: The standard Android emulator that comes with the SDK supports L, both for x86 and ARM images.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion has not provided android L support yet but they will in future.So for android development you have to rely on android sdk default emulator yet.I have used it and it is way faster than lower level versions.

Answer (score -2):

I always suggest [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) because it is faster than the stock emulator that comes with ADT. So, yeah go [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) !! *cheerleader dance*

Comment: AFAIK, Genymotion does not support "L".

Comment: @CommonsWare Not even the nexus images?

Comment: I'm not sure what "the nexus images" are. AFAIK, Genymotion needs source code, and AFAIK Genymotion tweeted last week that they'd support L if and when source became available.

Comment: The stock one that I had installed is not even working it never comes on @MrEngineer13

Comment: @CommonsWare Quick question: is it possible to design and test material theme on Galaxy S3 running 4.3 ?

Comment: @LittleChild: Not presently. The L material bits are for L only. Whether there will be any sort of backport of this stuff, once it ships "for realz", I cannot say.